# How can i make the ui text text to be sharper?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Before i used on the ui test Font Size 150 and the scale 1,1,1 but now i want the text to be smaller so i changed the font size to 30. and in the bottom i changed Horizontal overflow to Wrap and the Vertical overflow to Truncate.

The text under each button circle looks blurry and i want to keep the small size but make it sharper.

This is a screenshot of the buttons and example text under each one with date and time.

[image: blurry text]

Comment: as far as i see, you are still using a normal Unity Engine Text..
I would recommend to use the TextMeshPro(its free, official and you can download it from the unity package manager)

With TextMeshPro its much more sharper and lighter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **TextMeshPro**, it is a free package from unity. Just go to packages and install it.

The text looks much better and you have many more options to make it look better. (Outlines, underlay, different case types like all uppercase, smallcaps, etc)